# ASP.NET listview referential integrity

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have set up a Listview in ASP.NET, C#, SQL Server 2014 Express. I have also set a number of foreign keys in my database. When the user tries to delete something I would like the to tell them that "You can't delete this record because it exists in another table"

It all works fine when there are no referential integrity conflicts.

KitID would be a good example of one of the Foreign Keys in this Hardware table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Very new to ASP.NET so please don't assume too much knowledge when you reply. Thanks! :)

CODE BELOW

```
<div>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceHardware" runat="server" OnUpdating="SqlDataSourceHardware_Updating" EnableCaching="False"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Hardware] WHERE [HardwareID] = @HardwareID" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Hardware] ([HardwareName], [NSN], [AssetNo], [SerialNo], [ModelNo], [LastStockCheck], [StockCheckFreqDays], [DisposedOfDate], [DisposedBy], [WarrantyExpDate], [SustainedBy], [OwnedBy], [IsVirtualMachine], [NonTechFreqDays], [LastNonTechDate], [NonTechInstructions], [SignedOutBy], [Location], [LoanedTo], [LoanedToLocation], [ExpectedLoanReturnDate], [ServiceabilityID], [KitID], [ImagePath], [ImagePathThumb]) VALUES (@HardwareName, @NSN, @AssetNo, @SerialNo, @ModelNo, @LastStockCheck, @StockCheckFreqDays, @DisposedOfDate, @DisposedBy, @WarrantyExpDate, @SustainedBy, @OwnedBy, @IsVirtualMachine, @NonTechFreqDays, @LastNonTechDate, @NonTechInstructions, @SignedOutBy, @Location, @LoanedTo, @LoanedToLocation, @ExpectedLoanReturnDate, @ServiceabilityID, @KitID, @ImagePath, @ImagePathThumb)" 

        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Hardware] SET [HardwareName] = @HardwareName, [NSN] = @NSN, [AssetNo] = @AssetNo, [SerialNo] = @SerialNo, [ModelNo] = @ModelNo, [LastStockCheck] = @LastStockCheck, [StockCheckFreqDays] = @StockCheckFreqDays, [DisposedOfDate] = @DisposedOfDate, [DisposedBy] = @DisposedBy, [WarrantyExpDate] = @WarrantyExpDate, [SustainedBy] = @SustainedBy, [OwnedBy] = @OwnedBy, [IsVirtualMachine] = @IsVirtualMachine, [NonTechFreqDays] = @NonTechFreqDays, [LastNonTechDate] = @LastNonTechDate, [NonTechInstructions] = @NonTechInstructions, [SignedOutBy] = @SignedOutBy, [Location] = @Location, [LoanedTo] = @LoanedTo, [LoanedToLocation] = @LoanedToLocation, [ExpectedLoanReturnDate] = @ExpectedLoanReturnDate, [ImagePath] = @ImagePath, [ImagePathThumb] = @ImagePathThumb, [ServiceabilityID] = @ServiceabilityID, [KitID] = @KitID WHERE [HardwareID] = @HardwareID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="HardwareID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>

        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="HardwareName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="NSN" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="AssetNo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SerialNo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ModelNo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastStockCheck" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="StockCheckFreqDays" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DisposedOfDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DisposedBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="WarrantyExpDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SustainedBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="OwnedBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="IsVirtualMachine" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="NonTechFreqDays" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="LastNonTechDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="NonTechInstructions" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SignedOutBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Location" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LoanedTo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LoanedToLocation" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="ExpectedLoanReturnDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ServiceabilityID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="KitID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ImagePath" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ImagePathThumb" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="1" Name="HardwareID" 
                QueryStringField="HardwareID" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="HardwareName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="NSN" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="AssetNo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SerialNo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ModelNo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastStockCheck" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="StockCheckFreqDays" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DisposedOfDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="DisposedBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="WarrantyExpDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SustainedBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="OwnedBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="IsVirtualMachine" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="NonTechFreqDays" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="LastNonTechDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="NonTechInstructions" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SignedOutBy" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Location" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LoanedTo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LoanedToLocation" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="ExpectedLoanReturnDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ServiceabilityID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="KitID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="HardwareID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ImagePath" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ImagePathThumb" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="HardwareID" OnItemDeleted="FormView1_OnDeletedItem" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceHardware" 
        EmptyDataText="No Information Available<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />">
        <EditItemTemplate>

            <table id="HardwareItem" class="table table-bordered span12">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" class="span12">Details</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="span6">GeoQ ID:</td>
                        <td class="span6">
                            <asp:Label ID="HardwareIDLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("HardwareID") %>' />                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hardware Name:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="HardwareNameValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Hardware Name Required" ControlToValidate="HardwareNameTextBox" CssClass="ValidationError" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="HardwareNameTextBox" runat="server" maxlength="100" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("HardwareName") %>' />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>NSN:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="NSNTextBox" runat="server" maxlength="50" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("NSN") %>' />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Asset No:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="AssetNoTextBox" runat="server" maxlength="50" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("AssetNo") %>' />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Serial No:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="SerialNoValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Serial No Required" ControlToValidate="SerialNoTextBox" CssClass="ValidationError" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="SerialNoTextBox" runat="server" maxlength="50" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("SerialNo") %>' />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Model No:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ModelNoValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Model No Required" ControlToValidate="ModelNoTextBox" CssClass="ValidationError" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ModelNoTextBox" runat="server" maxlength="50" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("ModelNo") %>' />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Is This a Virtual Machine:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="IsVirtualMachineCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("IsVirtualMachine") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Serviceability:</td>
                        <td>               
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ServiceabilityValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Serviceability Required" ControlToValidate="DropDownListServiceability" CssClass="ValidationError" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListServiceability" runat="server" 
                                OnDataBound="AddNullValueToDropDownList_DataBound" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                                DataSourceID="ServiceabilityList" DataTextField="ServiceabilityName" DataValueField="ServiceabilityID"  
                                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ServiceabilityID") %>'>
                                <asp:listitem value="" text="Select a value"></asp:listitem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>

                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ServiceabilityList" runat="server" 
                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
                                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Serviceability]">
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>  

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Kit Name:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_Kit" runat="server" 
                                OnDataBound="AddNullValueToDropDownList_DataBound" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                                DataSourceID="KitList" DataTextField="KitName" DataValueField="KitID"  
                                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("KitID") %>'>
                                <asp:listitem value="" text="Select a kit"></asp:listitem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>

                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="KitList" runat="server" 
                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
                                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Kit]">
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>                         
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Image:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="ImageFileUpload" AllowMultiple="false" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="ImagePathHdn" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("ImagePath") %>' /> 
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="ImagePathThumbHdn" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("ImagePathThumb") %>' /> 
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="DBImagePath" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("fullPath") %>' /> 
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="DBImagePathThumb" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("fullPathThumb") %>' /> 
                            <div id="uploadPreview"><a rel="prettyPhoto" title="<%# Eval("HardwareName") %>" href="<%# Request.ApplicationPath + Eval("ImagePath")%>"><img ID="imgPreview" src="<%# Request.ApplicationPath + Eval("ImagePathThumb") + "?" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() %>" class="imgPreview img-rounded" onError="this.src='images/NoImage.png';" /></a></div>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>


          <div class="nopad">
            <table id="Governance" class="table table-bordered span12">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" class="span12">Governance</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>


                    <tr>
                        <td class="span6">Last Stock Check Date:</td>
                        <td class="span6">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="LastStockCheck_aspnetdatepicker" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("LastStockCheck", "{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>' />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Stock Check Frequency (Days):</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RangeValidator ID="StockCheckFreqDaysValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Range must be between 1 and 1000" MaximumValue="1000" MinimumValue="1" SetFocusOnError="True" CssClass="ValidationError" ControlToValidate="StockCheckFreqDaysTextBox" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="StockCheckFreqDaysTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("StockCheckFreqDays") %>' />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Disposed Of Date:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="DisposedOfDate_aspnetdatepicker" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("DisposedOfDate", "{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>' />                        
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Disposed By:</td>
                        <td>

                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_DisposedBy" runat="server" 
                                OnDataBound="AddNullValueToDropDownList_DataBound" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                                DataSourceID="ProfileList" DataTextField="UserName" DataValueField="UserId"  
                                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DisposedBy") %>'>
                                <asp:listitem value="" text="Select a person"></asp:listitem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Warranty Expiry Date:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="WarrantyExpDate_aspnetdatepicker" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("WarrantyExpDate", "{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>' />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Non-Tech Frequency (Days):</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RangeValidator ID="NonTechFreqDaysTextBoxValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Range must be between 1 and 1000" MaximumValue="1000" MinimumValue="1" SetFocusOnError="True" CssClass="ValidationError" ControlToValidate="NonTechFreqDaysTextBox" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="NonTechFreqDaysTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("NonTechFreqDays") %>' />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Non-Tech Date:</td>
                        <td>


                            <asp:TextBox ID="LastNonTechDate_aspnetdatepicker" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("LastNonTechDate", "{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>' />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Non-Tech Instructions:</td>
                        <td>


                            <asp:TextBox ID="NonTechInstructionstextarea" runat="server" 
                                TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("NonTechInstructions") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>


          <div class="nopad">
            <table id="Ownership" class="table table-bordered span12">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" class="span12">Ownership</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="span6">Sustained By:</td>
                        <td class="span6">

                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_SustainedBy" runat="server" 
                                OnDataBound="AddNullValueToDropDownList_DataBound" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                                DataSourceID="RoleList" DataTextField="RoleName" DataValueField="RoleId"  
                                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("SustainedBy") %>'>
                                <asp:listitem value="" text="Select a group"></asp:listitem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Owned By:</td>
                        <td>    
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="OwnerdByValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Owned By Required" ControlToValidate="DropDownList_OwnedBy" CssClass="ValidationError" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_OwnedBy" runat="server" 
                                OnDataBound="AddNullValueToDropDownList_DataBound" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                                DataSourceID="RoleList" DataTextField="RoleName" DataValueField="RoleId"  
                                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("OwnedBy") %>'>
                                <asp:listitem value="" text="Select a group"></asp:listitem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>                     
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>Signed Out By:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="SignedOutByValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Signed Out By Required" ControlToValidate="DropDownList_SignedOutBy" CssClass="ValidationError" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_SignedOutBy" runat="server" 
                                OnDataBound="AddNullValueToDropDownList_DataBound" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                                DataSourceID="ProfileList" DataTextField="UserName" DataValueField="UserId"  
                                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("SignedOutBy") %>'>
                                <asp:listitem value="" text="Select a person"></asp:listitem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>                         
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Location:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="LocationTextBox" runat="server" maxlength="50" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Location") %>' />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Loaned To:</td>
                        <td>    
                             <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_LoanedTo" runat="server" 
                                OnDataBound="AddNullValueToDropDownList_DataBound" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                                DataSourceID="ProfileList" DataTextField="UserName" DataValueField="UserId"  
                                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("LoanedTo") %>'>
                                <asp:listitem value="" text="Select a person"></asp:listitem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>                         
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Loaned To Location:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="LoanedToLocationTextBox" runat="server" maxlength="50" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("LoanedToLocation") %>' />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Expected Loan Return Date:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ExpectedLoanReturnDate_aspnetdatepicker" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("ExpectedLoanReturnDate", "{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>' />                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>



                </tbody>
            </table>


                    <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CssClass="btn marginR10 marginB10" 
                    CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn marginR10 marginB10" 
                    CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />  
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton_aspnetSimpleConfirmDelete" runat="server" OnClick="DeleteButton_aspnetSimpleConfirmDelete_Click" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="btn btn-danger marginR10 marginB10"  
                        OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');" 
                        CommandName="Delete" Text="<span class='icomoon-icon-remove white'></span> Delete " />


        </EditItemTemplate>

    </asp:FormView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ProfileList" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" SelectCommand="SELECT UserId, UserName FROM [aspnet_Users] ORDER BY UserName ASC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="RoleList" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [RoleName], [RoleId] FROM [vw_aspnet_Roles]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />

</div>
```

Comment: You could use a stored procedure as `DeleteCommand` to perform the deletion and return a value indicating whether the deletion was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Is the database designed with referential integrity? If not, do so.
Then just fire the delete command, and implement the `SqlDataSource.Deleted` event. You will find an event parameter, which contains an exception in case the referential integrity declined deleting the record. Then you can inform your user.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can check if the child table's record exists, prior your delete command, if the related tables have the id related to the parent table or not. If it exist then you can inform user which value exist.